# Calculating CPU usage for all PIDs

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system

I am making a Linux module to calculate CPU usage time for each task in the system. For this purpose, I am reading the task list using `for_each_process` to iterate over all `task_struct` entries. I have a couple of questions regarding this method:

1. In some of the code snippets, I have seen people using `for_each_process` with RCU lock. Is it necessarily required? I am only reading this data structure.
2. I am planning to use `utime` and `stime` fields of `task_struct`. But when I try to print these values, I find out that these values are different from the ones that I get using `cat /proc/<pid>/stat`.  There is a huge difference between these values. Am I doing something wrong?
3. As per my understanding, `utime` and `stime` represent the number of clock ticks. How can I derive the time elapsed in seconds from these values?

Apologies if these are kind of basic questions, I am kind of new to the Linux kernel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got some advice on Reddit.
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/kp55ev/calculating_cpu_usage_for_all_pids/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Also, instead of calculating the time in seconds, I am able to find a kernel function `task_cputime` that returns time in nanoseconds. I used this function and I am able to see the correct time results.